# Automatically update an UILabel at var update in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pointers

At some point of my project I got an UILabel displaying the number of element in an array.
I want to update automatically the label text when I modifying the array.
I can make my UILabel global and access it with a "didSet" on the array, but I don't want to make all my UILabel global (I got 8 UILabel for 8 different evolutive var).

Here is a way to update the UILabel content like a pointer or a reference on a specific variable ?

Edit
Some code example :
I got a global which is a dictionary,

```
let eg:[string : [SomeClass]]!
```

In a ViewController I got a UILabel, with

```
label.text = eg["key"].count
```

I want to automatically update the value display if I do something like that

```
eg["key"].append(something)
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I think using Property Observers is the right thing to do in your scenario...

Comment: I think didSet is the best solution.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I post an example, I got many UIlabel that I need to update, making a didSet is not a prob, but it mean I need to make my UIlabel accessible from outside the class, and I want to use a better solution.
I'm not using storyboards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using global data, one approach you might try is using NSNotificationCenter. If you were to encapsulate your global data inside an object, the object could post a notification every time the data is updated.

This approach will allow multiple observers the opportunity to act on changes to global state "automatically". It will also add the benefit of keeping your UIKit elements from being exposed.

Inside the userInfo property of the posted notification, you would place the key and associated count value.

Make your view controller an observer of this notification. When it receives the notification, it can update its UILabels itself, using the data received inside userInfo.

A simple implementation might look like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...
}

class MyGlobalObject {
    var eg:[String : [SomeClass]]!

    static let sharedInstance = MyGlobalObject()
    private init() {
        eg = ["someKey":[], "someOtherKey":[]]
    }

    func appendTo(key:String, value:SomeClass) {
        eg[key]?.append(value)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(NSNotification(name:"ValueChanged", object: nil, userInfo: ["Key":key, "Count" : (eg[key]?.count)!]))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Define labels, etc....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Put this wherever makes the most sense. viewWillAppear() works too. Don't forget to remove yourself as an observer when you are done.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"didUpdate:", name: "ValueChanged", object: nil)
    }

    func didUpdate(notif:NSNotification) {
        print("Received Notification!")
        let userInfo = notif.userInfo
        // Update appropriate label with the data
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in your app, you could do this:

```
MyGlobalObject.sharedInstance.appendTo("someKey", value: SomeClass())
```

Comment: Yes perfect ! I will adapt this to my project but it's completely what I was looking for ! :)